# List the names of items that had bids of $50 that did not sell, via relational algebra

Tags: relational-database, relational-algebra

I have the following relational database schema:

[image: schema]

I want to write the following query in relational algebra without using inequalities, disjunctions or conjunctions in the selection operator:

> List the names of items that had bids of $50 that did not sell.

I have come up with the following:

```
π iname (σ price=50 ((ITEM ⨝ BID) - π iid (SALE)))
```

Comment: Relational difference is only defined for 2 inputs with the same headings (attribute set/list ). It does a set difference, returning tuples from the left that are not in the right. But--when you *wrote* the minus, how did you think the operator acted? Why did you write it? Related operator anti-join returns left tuples that don't match any right tuples. You need to tell us what operators you can use, including definitions, including what a relation is defined to be (maybe by a reference to your textbook name & edition & what page). (There are many versions of relational algebras.)

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use a link/image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key.

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt is almost good.

I don't know the dimensions of your tables when one does the subtraction. One should always have the same dimension:

```
πiname(σprice=50((ITEM⨝BID) - πiid(ITEM⨝SALE)))
```

Comment: @cp101020304 What do you mean, make a difference? An expression with minus with arguments with different headings doesn't mean anything.